# Flask App builder is running on https mode. Open API server url shows http

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-appbuilder

I am using EKS cluster to deploy my service using https mode with secret. However the server is running and loading login page with https mode. When I tried to access

https://domainname/swagger/v1. The swagger open api server is showing http://domainname/.

[image]

Not understanding where should I change the configuration to display it in https mode.

When I checked the logs it showing as below.

```
[2023-04-26 06:01:54 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-04-26 06:01:54 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2023-04-26 06:01:54 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```